# Android JSON parsed data returning html characters

Tags: android, json

After parsing json data and displaying it in a textview, I noticed that it has some html characters like  &lsquo, &mdash, &quot, &#39, &rsquo, &nbsp, &ndash, and many others. How to deal with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are html entities. To transform them to readable text use `Html.fromHtml()`. Like this:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(jsonString));
```

Comment: problem solved! thank you! I'll just wait 7 minutes to accept it as an answer. :)